# How to make contents scrollable of spinner and limit Their width and height in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Image of my spinner:

[image: image of my spinner]

I need to implement something like this. I just want to show max. 3 or 4 items at a time and rest of the items should be scrollable.

If i have a total of 10 items in the dropdown, then only the 4 items should be visible at a time in the dropdown, and the other 6 items should be visible on scrolling down.

But what I'm getting is something like the attached image.

I have referred to below link but still not able to solve the issue.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60528/how-to-limit-the-height-for-a-spinner-dropdown-list

Comment: The reflection-based answer in your link works fine for a Android.Widget.Spinner

Comment: @SushiHangover  i have tried with android widget spinner but still didnt work for me.

Comment: check this [similar question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60528/how-to-limit-the-height-for-a-spinner-dropdown-list)

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar  Actually I have tried from that post only..but still didn't work for me

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: no i didn't find any solution